# How can I use assembler (or linker) to define a public symbol equal to an extern symbol?

Tags: windows, assembly, linker, code-generation, masm

In a code generation scenario I would like to emit assembly code (Microsoft toolchain, so MASM for 64-bit or 32-bit) so that I can define a `PUBLIC` symbol which will have the same value as some `EXTERN` symbol - in other words, sort of "forwarding" the symbol definition.  And then, the idea is that the linker will fix things up so that any use of the `PUBLIC` symbol will actually refer to the value of the `EXTERN` symbol.  The `EXTERN` symbol, of course, should be defined in some other object file.

As a concrete example, consider that I have some object file belonging to a library that extern's a symbol `To` which is the address of some function.  And now suppose I have a C header that declares a function `From` with proper signature.  My goal is an assembly language file that "equates" `From` with `To` so that when a file containing a function that calls `From` is linked together with the object file that holds `To` and the object file from this assembly language thunk then the linker will set things up so that the function `To` is called.

I'm currently doing this by generating `JMP` statements, such as:

```
PUBLIC From
EXTERN To
_TEXT  SEGMENT
From:
       JMP  To
_TEXT  ENDS
```

This works fine as far as it goes but for some purposes I'd rather not thunk via the `JMP`-instruction but instead I want calls to `From` to really be calls to `To`.  For example, I'd like to be able to take the address of `From` and get the address of the first byte of `To`, not the `JMP` instruction.

(If I can't do it via MASM then perhaps I can do it with some kind of LINK file of directives?  Alternatively, can I do it with another assembler besides MASM, or a different toolchain, preferably for Windows but otherwise for Linux?)

(I guess I should mention that

```
PUBLIC From
EXTERN To
From EQU Bar
```

doesn't work: `error A2014: cannot define as public or external : From`)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't the modules use `To` directly? Wouldn't `From` need to be "externed" in the other modules it's not defined in anyway?

Comment: @lurker I'm trying to get a tool that will proxy, in a specific sense, a C++ with another C++ class, at compile time (as opposed to runtime as is typical with proxies).  In some cases the target class is directly available, in such cases I want method calls on the proxy to be made directly to the methods of the target.  The C++ compiler has already externed the method names I'm looking at, when the target class' .cpp was compiled.

Comment: I think the shortcoming of the `EQU` is that it resolves everything at assembly time, but the `To` won't be resolved until link time. I don't have an answer (yet) off the top of my head, but somehow this (I think) requires directing the linker (as you hint at already in your reference to `LINK`) to allow an alternate symbol for the same entry point / label. The thunking you're doing now is probably the best you can do at assembly level.

Comment: You've probably looked at this already, but you could have a look at the [EXPORTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3.aspx) directive for the linker `.def` file. Specifically the `func2=func1` option. This might work if the only symbol exported is the alias, but if you need both the original `To` and the `From` exported, then it probably won't allow that.